# Issues with handleWatchKitExtensionRequest not being called?

Tags: ios, json, swift, parse-platform, apple-watch

I am trying to update my watch kit app to add some data that is parsed from a JSON file. I am doing this in combination with getting some data from Parse.

I am getting the error:

> The UIApplicationDelegate in the iPhone App never called reply() in -[UIApplicationDelegate application:handleWatchKitExtensionRequest:reply:]

I have tried to debug `handleWatchKitExtensionRequest` however it isn't crashing, and the `println` I've added is never printed for some reason.

This is my code:

```
func application(application: UIApplication, handleWatchKitExtensionRequest userInfo: [NSObject : AnyObject]?, reply: (([NSObject : AnyObject]!) -> Void)!) {
    var favouritesArrayDefaults: NSMutableArray! = [""]

    println("1")
    var keyStore = NSUbiquitousKeyValueStore()
    if keyStore.arrayForKey("FavouritesList") != nil {
        let tempFavourites: NSArray = keyStore.arrayForKey("FavouritesList")!
        favouritesArray = tempFavourites.mutableCopy() as! NSMutableArray
    } else {
        println("3")
    }

    println(favouritesArrayDefaults)

    if let pfqueryRequest: AnyObject = (userInfo as? [String: AnyObject])?["parkName"] {
        println("HELLO")

        let taskID = beginBackgroundUpdateTask()
        //Must start and end task to allow time for query to complete

        var name = ""
        var waitTime = ""
        var hasWaitTime = false
        var fastPass = false
        var heightRestriction = false
        var singleRider = false
        var disabledAccess = false
        var mustSee = false
        var fastPassTime = ""

        var namesArray: [String] = []
        var waitTimesArray: [String] = []
        var favouritesArray: [String] = []
        var hasWaitTimeArray: [Bool] = []
        var fastPassArray: [Bool] = []
        var heightRestrictionArray: [Bool] = []
        var singleRiderArray: [Bool] = []
        var disabledAccessArray: [Bool] = []
        var mustSeeArray: [Bool] = []
        var fastPassTimeArray: [String] = []

        var query = PFQuery(className: pfqueryRequest as! String)
        query.orderByAscending("Name")
        var objects = query.findObjects()

        if let objects = objects as? [PFObject] {
            for object in objects {
                name = (object.objectForKey("Name") as? String)!
                waitTime = (object.objectForKey("WaitTime") as? String)!
                hasWaitTime = (object.objectForKey("HasWaitTime") as? Bool)!
                fastPass = (object.objectForKey("FastPass") as? Bool)!
                heightRestriction = (object.objectForKey("HeightRestriction") as? Bool)!
                singleRider = (object.objectForKey("SingleRider") as? Bool)!
                disabledAccess = (object.objectForKey("DisabledAccess") as? Bool)!
                mustSee = (object.objectForKey("MustSee") as? Bool)!

                namesArray.append(name)
                waitTimesArray.append(waitTime)
                hasWaitTimeArray.append(hasWaitTime)
                fastPassArray.append(fastPass)
                heightRestrictionArray.append(heightRestriction)
                singleRiderArray.append(singleRider)
                disabledAccessArray.append(disabledAccess)
                mustSeeArray.append(mustSee)
            }

            var urlString = (DataManager.sharedInstance.getParkByName(pfqueryRequest as! String)?.dataSource)!

            if let url = NSURL(string: urlString) {
                if let data = NSData(contentsOfURL: url, options: .allZeros, error: nil) {
                    let json = JSON(data: data)

                    for count in 0...json.count - 1 {
                        let rideName: JSON = json[count]["name"]
                        let waitTime: JSON = json[count]["waitTime"]
                        var fastPassTime: JSON = json[count]["fastPass"]

                        if find(namesArray, rideName.string!) != nil {
                            let index = find(namesArray, rideName.string!)

                            var modifiedWaitTime = "".join(waitTime.string!.componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet(NSCharacterSet.decimalDigitCharacterSet().invertedSet))

                            if waitTime == "Down" || waitTime == "Closed" {
                                modifiedWaitTime = "Closed"
                            }

                            if fastPassTime.string == nil {
                                fastPassTime = "Unavailable"
                            } else if fastPassTime.string == "N/A" {
                                fastPassTime = "Expired"
                            }

                            waitTimesArray.removeAtIndex(index!)
                            waitTimesArray.insert(waitTime.string!, atIndex: index!)

                            fastPassTimeArray.removeAtIndex(index!)
                            fastPassTimeArray.insert(fastPassTime.string!, atIndex: index!)
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            for favourite in favouritesArrayDefaults {
                favouritesArray.append(favourite as! String)
            }

            println(fastPassTimeArray)
            reply(["success": true, "name": namesArray, "waitTime": waitTimesArray, "hasWaitTime": hasWaitTimeArray, "favourites": favouritesArray, "fastPass": fastPassArray, "heightRestriction": heightRestrictionArray, "singleRider": singleRiderArray, "disabledAccess": disabledAccessArray, "mustSee": mustSeeArray, "fastPassTime": fastPassTimeArray])

            endBackgroundUpdateTask(taskID)
        }
    } else if let pfqueryRequest: AnyObject = (userInfo as? [String: AnyObject])?["parkNameSubmit"] {
        let taskID = beginBackgroundUpdateTask()

        var query = PFQuery(className: pfqueryRequest as! String)
        //query.orderByAscending("Name")
        query.whereKey("Name", equalTo: userInfo!["name"]!)
        query.getFirstObjectInBackgroundWithBlock {
            (object: PFObject?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
            if error != nil {
                println("The getFirstObject request failed.")
            } else {
                if let obj = object {
                    obj.setValue(userInfo!["waitTime"], forKey: "WaitTime")
                    obj.saveInBackground()
                }
                println("Successfully retrieved the object.")
            }
        }

        reply(["success": true, "message": "Hello!"])

        endBackgroundUpdateTask(taskID)
    }
}
```

I apologise for the extensive code, but I really have no idea where the issue is.

Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Was this ever resolved?

Answer (score 0):

Put your `reply()` call into the "Irrelevant code" section. The thing is the `reply()` handler should be called in any case but in your example if `pfqueryRequest` is `nil` the handler never won't be called.

Comment: I have another reply within the irrelevant code. I'll update my code to demonstrate.

Comment: I guess you made a mistake? You should have a closing condition with the `else` block, not `else if` one.

Comment: I've added an `else` now, but it doesn't make a difference. I should add that I had the same code (minus the JSON stuff) and it worked fine before.

Comment: Ok, what if you call `reply()` in the last line of your handler - it should work. I have never had any problems with processing of this handler.

Comment: Yeah, it gets called in the very last line.

Comment: Another point: The `initWithContentsOfURL:options:error:` constructor of `NSData` is synchronous (it possibly can take considerable time) and it gets called before any `reply()` so it could easily cause the error.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89695/discussion-between-dmitry-gutsulyak-and-user3746428).

Answer (score 0):

**Serializing Custom Objects in the `reply()` handler**

Another reason this error could be occurring is [if you are attempting to send a custom object in the `reply()` handler](http://www.kristinathai.com/watchkit-best-practices-for-sharing-data-between-your-watch-and-ios-app/). If you try to do this, iOS/watchOS will be unable to serialize your objects to the reply's `plist` file, which is how this communication takes place. Since the file serialization fails, the file is never written out and the WatchKit Extension thinks that `reply()` was never called, hence the error.

You must either break these objects down into more basic object types or use `NSKeyedArchiver` to encode those custom objects as `NSData` before being sent in the reply and to decode then use `NSKeyedUnarchiver` to decode that data back into your custom object on the extension side of the communication.

**Start Background Task Immediately to prevent iOS from suspending your App**

You also [need to start the background task as the very first thing in your handler](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplicationDelegate_Protocol/index.html?hl=ar#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIApplicationDelegate/application:handleWatchKitExtensionRequest:reply:), otherwise iOS can suspend your App's execution (even if all you were doing is validating the request or creating a variable first).

From [Apple's *`UIApplicationDelegate` Protocol Reference*](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplicationDelegate_Protocol/index.html?hl=ar#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIApplicationDelegate/application:handleWatchKitExtensionRequest:reply:):

> **Because this method is likely to be called while your app is in the background, call the beginBackgroundTaskWithName:expirationHandler: method at the start of your implementation** and the endBackgroundTask: method after you have processed the reply and executed the reply block. Starting a background task ensures that your app is not suspended before it has a chance to send its reply.

**Xcode Console Output from iOS App not Available when attached to WatchKit Extension process**

When you are debugging on the WatchKit Extension, `print()`, `println()`, `NSLog()` or similar methods of writing to the console from the iOS App will not be shown.

One way to get around this is to run the WatchKit App in the simulator, then open the iOS App in the iOS Simulator. Once you've done that, go back to Xcode and go to `Debug > Attach to Process` and find your iOS App's process in the list. Xcode should now show console output from both processes (however you will need to switch between them using the controls at the top of the Debugging/Console area of Xcode.

**Utilize the newer WatchKit APIs in the Watch Connectivity Framework**

I highly recommend the newer [Watch Connectivity Framework](https://developer.apple.com/library/watchos/documentation/WatchConnectivity/Reference/WatchConnectivity_framework/) over the older usage of `+[WKInterfaceController openParentApplication:reply:]`. Apple has done a lot of work to improve upon the initial mechanisms for sharing data between a watchOS app and its host iOS app.

I personally, had a lot of issues using the original APIs and all of them went away when I dropped support for watchOS 1.x and moved to watchOS 2.x and later.